# time required to Build server configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, backup, oracle, solaris

I need an advice on time required to build the following items.
1) oracle 10g installtion
2) Apache web server
3) Solaris OS
4) Setting of backup service for server
5) Big IP Load balancer

A quick response will be appreciated.

Comment: There are way too many factors involved to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Given all the things required to build, how much time will it take?

Comment: If I've got VM images to base servers on, and proper hypervisor infrastructure to deploy on; I could do it all in an afternoon. Starting from scratch with all physical hardware; 100+ man-hours depending on the exact requirements. But as many other have stated, there so much more we'd need to know if you want a half way accurate number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on the experience of who is doing it and what kind of config you need.
For example, if you know apache and have the sites config files already ready (or simple) it can take below 30 minutes installing with deb packages and configuring everything (vhosts, apache conf, ssl, DNS) but takes much more if you compile it (mainly if you have never done that before... can take some days).

On the OS time it is worse as if you don't need to configure it (for some testing for example) it can be really quick (below 1 hour) or can take from week to weeks if you will set firewall, LDAP client or server, samba or who knows... and you don't know how to do it and need to figure out how to do.

Knowledge of the installed OS is also a critical point for the time needed, but supposing you know the OS and waht you need to install on it well and do not need big configs, you can have it running in around half-day to a day. If you already have scripts (or a set of copy/paste commands) to do it, less than that.

Answer (score 5):

1. 6 days
2. 136 minutes
3. Oranges
4. Ask again tomorrow

Seriously though, can you provide more details on your objective?

Comment: I almost upvoted that on comedic value alone!

Comment: LOL... hopefully the OP will post more details. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, who is actually doing the build?

An expert who builds a Solaris server multiple times a day it may take a couple of hours.  Someone who's never done it before it may take a couple of weeks to get the config right.

What's the purpose of the question?  For you to estimate/quote on work?  If it's to validate another company's estimate of time required then you probably won't be able to with those details.  You're better off asking yourself whether you trust the other company not to rip you off...!

Answer (score 0):

In reagrds to the Oracle installation, are you talking about just installing the software (which I would assume to include the latest patchset plus CPUs), or should that including creating and configuring a database. If the latter, are you including user setup, tablespaces....